# two or more data types in declaration specifiers

Tags: c, declaration, specifier

I've looked around and tried a few things, nothings working at the moment.

```
main.c:13: error: two or more data types in declaration specifiers
make[1]: *** [main.o] Error 1
make: *** [build] Error 2
```

My code is pretty much this(i've commented everything out so it's not something else + there are no other files apart from this);

**main.h**

```
struct savetype{
    bool file_exists;
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include "main.h"
extern struct savetype save;
int main (void){
return 0;
}
```

**stuff.c**

```
#include "main.h"
struct savetype save;
save.file_exists=true;
```

Comment: Also, if i add a semicolon to "struct savetype{/*stuff*/}" in main.h, i get this error:

stuff.c:4: error: expected '=', ',', '
', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '.' token

Comment: I don't believe that there's a bool datatype in C.

Comment: @Rafe: c99 has a native `bool` type, and most compilers support it these days.

Comment: @dmckee: `bool` is visible only if you have `#include <stdbool.h>`.

Answer (score 2):

C struct declarations must end with a semicolon. Put a semicolon at the end of your struct declaration in `main.h` and you'll be OK.

Also, there should be a `bool` type available to you unless you've got some other code defining it. In C, use an `int` instead of a bool.

Moreover, there's no such thing as `true` in standard C; 0 is false and anything else is true, so you'll have to correct stuff.c as well.

Also, stuff.c shouldn't compile because it contains code (more than just declarations) outside of any function (specifically `save.file_exists = true;`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem:

```
struct savetype{
    bool file_exists;
};
^^^^ <-------------- Here!
```

You forgot a semicolon in the end.

Answer (score 1):

bool type doesn't exist in C. you can use a macro to use TRUE/FALSE values in a convenient way:

```
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0
```

then you can use it in conditional statements like this:

```
if (var == TRUE){

}
```

if you want to use 'bool' as a keyword:

```
typedef int bool;
```

EDIT:

I didn't know that but @Bo Persson pointed out that from C99 boolean types have been introduced. To use them include the following prototype:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
```

Comment: @Bo Persson: thanks. I din't know that. Do you think I should remove my answer?

Comment: If it's not correct you can either fix it, or remove it. That's up to you!

Comment: `if (var == TRUE)` is unnecessary and dangerous.  If `var` represents a condition, just write `if (var)` -- and give it a name for which that makes sense.  Remember that *any* non-zero value us true in a condition.